# get a value from $promise returned by Item.query()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongoose, mean-stack

Hello I am trying to query my Mongoose DB for items using `$scope.inventory = Item.query();` which works. Problem is I need to separate them based on a values on the front end of my app.

`console.log($scope.inventory);` returns `[$promise: Promise, $resolved: false]` which from the console I can drill into and find the values but I cant find a way of accessing them in my code.
[image]

Comment: `Item.query().$promise.then(function(data){ $scope.inventory=data;  })` Chain through the promise. Return value from the $resource actually gets expanded later to the same return object when the call is fulfilled, that what you see in the console, You can verify that by printing `$scope.inventory.length` it will just print `0` when you try to access it right after

Comment: Again you made my day! Thanks PSL